# JavaFX + eGalax Touchscreen + Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi

Hi guys I need help with my School Project.
We have a 7 inch eGalax Touchscreen which is fully calibrated and as soon as we start our JavaFx Program the x and y axis are switched. I move right, it moves up...

I'm frustrated with this problem. I searched in several internet forums for hours but nothing helps!

Please if you have a Solution for this help me!

EDIT 1: The Screen is 90 degrees rotated in boot.conf

Comment: Show us you code please.

Comment: @gvmani Why do you need my code? just curious.

Comment: @Hiabst I'm not 100% sure but latest JavaFX is not running on Raspberry Pi. Oracle decided not to support it because there is not market for this JVM edition. Please someone correct me if I'm wrong. You have to build OpenJDK from source code manually.

Comment: @PeterPenzov that will be not easy i guess?

Comment: @Hiabst you have to spend a lot of time on this. Next time make a research before you choose hardware and software.

Comment: @PeterPenzov ok but isn't there another solution for this because our project will finish in 2 weeks from now.

Comment: @Hiabst You can ask JavaFX developers here http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev

Comment: I think you just need OpenJDK 8 (or later). See https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/OpenJFX+on+the+Raspberry+Pi

Comment: @James_D ok i'll try it when im home, thanks!

Comment: @James_D i can't find OpenJDK 8 only the OJDK 7...